# Windows 10 not shutting down

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I recently installed Windows 10 Enterprise (clean install, not update). Since then, i am experiencing a weird problem. Most of the times the laptop (Dell Inspiron 15) is not shutting down properly. The screen goes black but I can hear the fan of the cooling base working. Then I need to press the power button for 2-3 seconds in order to shut down my machine. Even if I do nothing for half an hour, the fan continues working and the laptop starts overheating. I turned off fast startup but the problem still remains. I have performed all of the latest Windows and driver updates. Any helpful suggestion? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What is your hardware and what drivers are you using? Is computer shutting down properly in safe mode? Try "sfc /scannow" and also "Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth" in cmd as admin

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Intel Virtualization Technology enabled in the BIOS?  This is a known issue at the moment and Microsoft are aware.  Mine does the same at the moment, and if I turn off Intel VT it works fine.

Comment: I disabled the Intel Virtualization technology from the BIOS but the problem remains. Thanks.